# Cast functions in scala

Tags: scala

I have the base class `Message` and two derived classes `One` and `Two`. Method `regHandler` accepts function `Message => Message` as argument. When i created method `handler` and passed it to `regHandler`, it throws cast error.

```
class Message

class One extends Message
class Two extends Message
type Handler = Message => Message

def regHandler(handler: Handler) {}

def handler(one: One) : Two = {
  new Two
}

regHandler(handler) // <- error here
```

I tried change my code like this:

```
var f : Handler

def regHandler[T >: Message, R >: Message](handler: T => R) = {
  f = handler // <- but cast error here occurred
}
```

How do i need change my code to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variance annotation with wildcard types. Check this:

```
object Main {

  class Message

  class One extends Message

  class Two extends Message

  class Three extends Message

  class Four extends Message

  type HandlerType[+A <: Message, +B <: Message] = A => B

  var f: HandlerType[_, _] = _

  def regHandler(handler: HandlerType[_, _]) = {
    f = handler // <- but cast error here occurred
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def handler12(x: One): Two = new Two

    def handler23(x: Two): Three = new Three

    def handler34(x: Three): Four = new Four

    val h12 = handler12(_)
    val h23 = handler23(_)
    val h34 = handler34(_)

    val handlersMap: Map[String, HandlerType[_, _]] = Map(
      "12" -> h12,
      "23" -> h23,
      "34" -> h34)

    handlersMap foreach {
      case (k, h) =>
        println(k)
        println(h)
        val hd: HandlerType[Message, Message] = h
        val m: Message = new One
        println(hd(m))
    }

    regHandler(h12)

  }
}
```

Although you can store the handlers into a map, it creates additional types which introduce more complexity. I think there should be a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: This shouldn't compile (http://scastie.org/12061: `covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type [+A <: Main.Message, +B <: Main.Message]A => B of type HandlerType`). And if it did, it wouldn't work, since it calls `h23(new One)` as well as `h34(new One)`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: You are right, it doesn't compile. However it does allow to store in a `Map`, which the OP requested. When I said complexity in my answer, I meant exactly that same compilation error. I am yet to figure out, how to resolve this error.

Comment: But the error isn't introduced by storing handlers in a map, but by an incorrect definition of `HandlerType`. You can just use `Handler` and store them in a map without any problems, if you actually have `Handler`s; the OP's problem is that he doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good reason it doesn't work: your `Handler` definition says it accepts any `Message`, but `handler` only accepts `One`. Kolberg proposes one solution, but the simpler one would be just to fix `handler`:

```
def handler(m: Message) = m match {
  case one: One => new Two
  case _ => // whatever you want to do here
}
```

You can throw an exception, which would be equivalent to other answers, except you can have a better error message; you can remove the line, which will throw `MatchError`; you can return `Option[Message]`; etc.

Now you can assign it, store it in a map, etc. easily:

```
object Main extends App {
  class Message
  class One extends Message
  class Two extends Message
  type Handler = Message => Message

  def regHandler(handler: Handler) {}

  def handler(m: Message) = m match {
    case one: One => new Two
    case _        => throw new Exception(s"handler expected One, got $m")
  }

  regHandler(handler)

  val f: Handler = handler // no _ required

  val map: Map[String, Handler] = Map("1" -> handler)
}
```

Or if you really don't want to change method signatures, make `Handlers` out of them explicitly (it could be an implicit conversion as well, but since it can introduce errors, I don't recommend it):

```
object Handler {
  def apply[A <: Message, B <: Message](f: A => B): Handler = f.asInstanceOf[Handler]

  // alternately if you want to handle ClassCastException for wrong argument type
  // def apply[A <: Message, B <: Message](f: A => B): Handler = 
  //   x => try { f(x) } catch { case e: ClassCastException => ... }
}

regHandler(Handler(handler))
```

Answer (score 1):

The type bounds in

```
def regHandler[T >: Message, R >: Message](handler: T => R) = {
```

are wrong, because with `>:` you are telling the compiler that `T,R` should be super types of `Message`. I think you want sub types of `Message`:

```
def regHandler[T <: Message, T <: Message](handler: T => R) {}

def handler(one: One) : Two = {
  new Two
}

regHandler(handler)
```

works for me.

EDIT:

OK, my answer was incomplete. Here is a complete and working example:

```
class Message

class One extends Message
class Two extends Message
type Handler[A <: Message, B <: Message] = A => B

def regHandler[A <: Message, B <: Message](a: A)(handler: Handler[A, B]): Unit = {
  println(s"${handler(a)}")
}

def handler(one: One) : Two = {
  new Two
}

regHandler(new One)(handler)
```

**EDIT 2:**
For usage in a map function or to assign to a var/val in this specific scenario add `_`:

```
val f: Handler[_, _] = handler _

val map = Map(new One -> handler _)
val test = map.map {case (one, h) => h(one)}
```

Comment: After update all works fine but my old task is not complete fully. My initial question is: why can't i assign `f = handler`. `println(s"${handler(a)}")` works but assign doesn't.

Comment: it has a sense when you need put your handler to the map

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg That's wrong. You don't need it "To assign a Function to a var/val", you need it to get a `Function` from a method (in some contexts).